# Refresh the page until a specific string appears in a certain part of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a script that refreshes a webpage until a specific string appears e.g "John Smith." However the string appears already apears in the page but I want it to only stop refreshing when it appears in a specific part of the page. How would I do that?

```
var FREQUENCY = 300000;

var text = document.body.innerHTMl || document.body.textContent;
var yourTime = new Date();

if (text.indexOf("John Smith") < 0) {
    alert(yourTime);
} else {
    var lastCheck = document.createElement("div");
    lastCheck.innerHTML = "Last Check: " + yourTime.toString();
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
    parent.insertBefore(lastCheck, parent.children[1]);

    window.setTimeout(window.location.reload, FREQUENCY);
}
```

Comment: Okay, what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suggest, you know exactly where this special string is in the DOM.
Then, you'll need to do the query on that element and the first part of the question should be clear. You'd either have an ID of the element, class names or [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

Regarding the reloading, you'll need to find a way to stop it.
The simplest way is to skip it. Something like this:

```
var isStringFound = text.indexOf("John Smith") > -1;
if (isStringFound === false) {
    window.location.reload
}
```

So, the final code would be something like this:

```
var DOMToSerach = document.querySelector("#specialSecion");
var text = DOMToSerach.innerText || "";
var isStringFound = text.indexOf("John Smith") > -1;
if (isStringFound === false) {
    window.location.reload
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check `reloaded` in localStorage  before `window.location.reload` and then you can set a flag `reloaded` to localStorage